Markov and Supermartingale with stopping time $\tau$
Let $X_n$, $n\geq 0$, be a non-negative integer valued integrable markov chain with transition probabilities
$$ p(j|i) = 
\begin{cases} 
p_n & j=(i-1)\vee 0 \\ 
1-p_n & j=i+1 \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
where $p_n\in(\frac{2}{3},0)$ $\forall n$. Let $\mathcal{F}_n := \sigma(X_m, m\leq n)$, $n\geq 0$, and $\tau:=\text{min}\{n\geq 0: X_n=0)\}$.
Show that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(X_{n\wedge \tau}+\epsilon n\wedge\tau, \mathcal{F}_{n\wedge \tau}), n\geq 0$, is a supermartingale.
My Solution:
\begin{align*}E[X_{(n+1)\wedge \tau} + \epsilon(n+1)\wedge\tau|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge\tau}] &= E[X_{(n+1)\wedge \tau}|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge\tau}] + \epsilon E[(n+1)\wedge\tau|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge\tau}]\\
&= E[X_{(n+1)\wedge \tau}|X_{n\wedge\tau}] + \epsilon E[(n+1)\wedge\tau|X_{n\wedge\tau}]\\
&\leq X_{n\wedge\tau}+\epsilon n\wedge\tau \end{align*}
My Questions:

For showing the
$(X_{n\wedge \tau}+\epsilon n\wedge\tau, \mathcal{F}_{n\wedge \tau}), n\geq 0$, is a supermartingale. Do I need to show that $$E[X_{n\wedge\tau +1}+\epsilon(n\wedge\tau+1)|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge\tau}]\leq X_n+\epsilon n\wedge\tau$$ or my solution is correct?
How do I show if $X_0=N>0$, then $E[\tau]\leq\frac{N}{\epsilon}$ using the above fact?

Thanks in advance.
